# How to add lang attribute to <html> using htmlwebpack plugin

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

My template file is coming from some other projects and I don't know that. I have to add lang property to the template file using htmlwebpack plugin. How can I do the same.

```
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            showErrors: true,
            minify: false,
            hash: true,
            path: Config.output,
            title: '',
            template: Config.htmlEntry,
            filename: 'index.html',
            
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Currently html file generated in dist folder is like below
````<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="index"></section>
</body>

</html>
````
I want to lang attribute in it through htmlwebpack plugin so that the geneated file have lang attribute like   ````<html lang="en"> </html>````

Comment: Why not add the "lang" attribute to the HTML template directly?